# xtlogit in R - logit fixed effects

Tags: r, binary, panel

I'm trying to figure out how to perform a fixed effect logit regression in R (analogously to Stata's xtlogit command). I read of several packages such as "pglm" or "bife" but couldn't get my model to run.

My data is saved as a data frame and looks like:

```
ID   Time  Y  X
1    2000  1  0
1    2001  0  1
1    2002  1  1
...
1    2016  1  0
...
n
```

Basically I would like to run the fixed effects logit regression:

```
 y_jt = beta*x_jt + mu_j + pi_t + epsilon_jt
```

where j is the ID, t is the Time, mu the ID fixed effects, pi the time fixed effects, and epsilon the error term.

I'm open to using any package. I started with "bife" but could not figure out how to set both ID and Time fixed effects. I tried:

```
 mod.no <- bife(y ~ x | ID, data = panel)
```

Do I maybe need to set the data as a panel like Stata's "xtset" command?

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

The Stata command I would like to replicate in R is:

```
xi: xtlogit Y X i.Time, fe
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, I think the strategy here would be to do the following:

1. Create a variable containing the individual-level mean for the predictor variable. This is most easily accomplished using `dplyr`:

   `data <- data $>$ group_by(ID) %>% mutate(X_mean = mean(X))`

The magic here is with the `group_by` function, which causes the `mean` operation to calculate group means rather than global means.

2. Use `lme4` to estimate the logit model as a multilevel model. Here's how I'd specify the model:

   `glmer(Y ~ X + X_mean + Time + (1 | ID), family = binomial)`

The terms "fixed" and "random" are really muddled between the panel data, multilevel modeling, and some other literatures, so I'm not completely clear on how you conceptualize "fixed effect of time". What this model gives you is a fixed effect of `X` in that the coefficient for `X` will represent the within-subjects effect of `X`. I include `Time` as a predictor which will either treat the year as an additional predictor whose interpretation depends on whether it is continuous or categorical. Some would fit that as a "random" effect (as in random slope or in some literatures a "growth curve"). You would do that with:

`glmer(Y ~ X + X_mean + Time + (Time | ID), family = binomial)`

Which estimates a different effect of time for every individual.

The `(1 | ID)` in the first model and `(Time | ID)` in the second model tells `lme4` what the grouping variable is, which in your case is `ID`. You get random intercepts by `ID` in the first model and a random intercept plus random slope for `Time` in the second model. Another interpretation of your first post would be that you want a random intercept for `Time` as well, in which case you could do the following:

`glmer(Y ~ X + X_mean + (1 | Time) + (1 | ID), family = binomial)`

or, alternatively, if there are few waves you can get to the same place by including `Time` as a predictor and making that variable a factor in your input data. If there are many time points that could make the output unwieldy.

I've been working on a package to automate some of this, inspired by the `xt` suite from Stata, though at this juncture my package is far more limited. It's called `panelr` and at present must be downloaded from GitHub. More info available here: https://github.com/jacob-long/panelr

In this case, using `panelr`, your situation would work like this:

```
library(panelr)
pdata <- panel_data(data, id = ID, wave = Time)
model <- wbm(Y ~ X, data = pdata, use.wave = TRUE, family = binomial)
```

All `panelr` is doing is automating what I've explained above. You can drop the individual mean variable without affecting the estimate of the within-subject effect of `X` by using the `model = "within"` argument.

`panelr` is probably a few weeks away from CRAN submission at this point as a few things need documenting, there are a few edge cases where things break unexpectedly, and I want to be more flexible about the handling of time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it out. It seems though rather complicated to me. Is there no way how to do this with the pglm or bife package?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try coercing the `Time` variable to a factor, like you are doing in Stata, and including it in the `bife` formula:

```
panel$Time <– as.factor(panel$Time)

mod.no <- bife(y ~ x + Time | ID, data = panel, bias_corr = "ana")
```

Note: You will probably want to correct for the incidental parameter bias with the `bias_corr = "ana"` at the end.

Alternatively, using the `clogit` function in the `survival` package should work too:

```
mod.no <– clogit(y ~ x + strata(Time) + strata(ID), data = panel
```

The `strata()` option indicates the fixed-effects.